# MySQL nested left join with outer references

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say we have these (simplified from a more complex one) example tables:

```
== st ==    == pr ===   == rn ===  <– tables
sta   pg    pg    rou   sta   rou  <– fields
========    =========   =========
H1    aa    aa    aaA   H1    aaA

H2    aa    aa    aaB   H2    aaB
H3    aa                H3    aaB

H4    aa    aa    aaC   H4    aaC
H5    aa                H5    aaC
H6    aa                H6    aaC

H7    aa

H8    bb    bb    NULL
```

I wanted to execute this (also simplified) query with an inner left join:

```
SELECT st.*, pr.*, rn.*
FROM         st
INNER JOIN ( pr
LEFT  JOIN   rn  ON pr.rou = rn.rou
                AND          rn.sta = st.sta -- ERROR here
           )     ON pr.pg =           st.pg
-- filter out bad rows
WHERE ( rn.id )                          -- a: not null
   OR ( pr.rou ='aaC' AND rn.id IS NULL) -- b: no joinable rn found: choose
                                         --    by a predefined pr.rou value
   OR ( pr.rou IS NULL )                 -- c: no need to join
```

to have this result:

```
== st ==    == pr ===   == rn ===
sta   pg    pg    rou   sta   rou
========    =========   =========
H1    aa    aa    aaA   H1    aaA
H2    aa    aa    aaB   H2    aaB
H3    aa    aa    aaB   H3    aaB
H4    aa    aa    aaC   H4    aaC
H5    aa    aa    aaC   H5    aaC
H6    aa    aa    aaC   H6    aaC

H7    aa    aa    aaA   NULL  NULL \  H7 has no rn, so choose
H7    aa    aa    aaB   NULL  NULL  } 1 row of these at the
H7    aa    aa    aaC   NULL  NULL /  WHERE / b condition

H8    bb    bb    NULL  NULL  NULL
```

but MySQL throws up this error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'st.sta' in 'on clause'`.

I tried to solve this with no success, until somebody posted (and deleted) a nice idea of joining the `rn` column twice. Thanks to him/her, I was able to create a working solution:

```
SELECT st.*, pr.*, rn.*, rn2.*

FROM         st
INNER JOIN   pr         ON st.pg = pr.pg
LEFT  JOIN   rn         ON st.sta = rn.sta
LEFT  JOIN   rn AS rn2  ON pr.rou = rn2.rou -- the two rn's join order is important
                       AND rn.id  = rn2.id  -- if first exists, second must match or null, first null => second null
WHERE ( rn.id = rn2.id )                    -- a: both not null
   OR ( pr.rou ='aaC' AND rn.id IS NULL)    -- b: no joinable rn found: choose by predefined pr.rou value
   OR ( pr.rou IS NULL )                    -- c: no need to join
```

While this query works, it requires the duplicate joins in the right order, very fragile, and ugly.

Can you give a cleaner solution, which joins the `rn` table only once?

Here is the sample database in sql for copypasting, if you want to play with it:

```
DROP    TABLE IF     EXISTS st;
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS st (
  id  int  AUTO_INCREMENT,
  sta varchar(9),
  pg  varchar(9),
  PRIMARY KEY ( id )
)  AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

DROP    TABLE IF     EXISTS pr;
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pr (
  id  int  AUTO_INCREMENT,
  pg  varchar(9),
  rou varchar(9),
  PRIMARY KEY ( id )
)  AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

DROP    TABLE IF     EXISTS rn;
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rn (
  id  int  AUTO_INCREMENT,
  sta varchar(9),
  rou varchar(9),
  PRIMARY KEY ( id )
)  AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


INSERT INTO st 
(sta , pg ) VALUES
('H1','aa'),
('H2','aa'),
('H3','aa'),
('H4','aa'),
('H5','aa'),
('H6','aa'),
('H7','aa'),
('H8','bb');
INSERT INTO pr
( pg , rou ) VALUES
('aa','aaA'),
('aa','aaB'),
('aa','aaC'),
('bb', NULL);
INSERT INTO rn
(sta , rou ) VALUES
('H1','aaA'),
('H2','aaB'),
('H3','aaB'),
('H4','aaC'),
('H5','aaC'),
('H6','aaC');
```

Comment: If some of the answers below seem to make no sense, it is because I had to edit my question a few times.

Comment: Can you please clarify the basis on how your  H4, H5, and H6 are referring to H1, H2 and H3 respectively, it doesn't appear to make sense since the rn table HAS a corresponding "sta" value that matches your "st" table

Comment: Sorry, this is the result of careless copypasting, fixed it now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I've finally got it:

```
SELECT st.*, pr.*, rn.*
FROM st
  LEFT JOIN rn ON st.sta = rn.sta
  LEFT JOIN pr ON st.pg  = pr.pg
              AND (rn.rou = pr.rou OR rn.rou IS NULL)
```

Comment: Just perfect. Thank you! I feel myself really dumb now :) I extended the last join condition to
   `st.pg  = pr.pg
            AND ( rn.rou IS     NULL OR pr.rou = rn.rou )
            AND ( rn.rou IS NOT NULL OR pr.rou IS NULL OR  pr.rou = 'aaC' )`, and it works really beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

```
select st.*, pr.*, rn.*  
from st
left join  pr on pr.pg = st.pg
left  join   rn  on rn.sta = st.sta
```

Comment: Thanks, but the `pr.rou = rn.rou` condition seems to be missing :)

Comment: I've tried your dump and the query gives your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this quickly and it appeared to work.  I renamed the columns to show the context of what they should be representing to match your expected results.

```
SELECT 
      st.sta,
      st.pg,
      MIN( COALESCE( prByRN.pg, pr.pg )) prpg,
      MIN( COALESCE( prByRN.rou, pr.rou )) prrou,
      MIN( rn.sta ) rnsta,
      MIN( rn.rou ) rnrou
   from
      st
         left join rn
            ON st.sta = rn.sta 
            LEFT JOIN pr prByrn
               ON rn.rou = prByrn.rou
         LEFT JOIN pr
            ON st.pg = pr.pg
   GROUP BY 
      st.sta,
      st.pg
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really does work, but I had to accept Andriy's solution for is simplicity (even if I had to modify it a bit).

Answer (score 1):

This Query is 100 % True...

Check it .....

```
Select st.sta,st.pg,pr.pg,pr.rou,rn.sta,rn.rou from st
    Left join pr 
                     On pr.pg=st.pg
    Left join rn 
                     On rn.sta=st.sta
```

your result is given these query...

If Any doubt then reply as soon as fast.

Comment: Thank you, it worked, but i had to give the bounty to Andriy, he was earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT st.*, pr.*, rn.*
FROM 
    st
  LEFT  JOIN 
      ( pr                          --- the parenthesis are
      LEFT  JOIN 
        rn 
          ON  pr.rou = rn.rou
      )                             --- there for clarity
    ON  rn.sta = st.sta 
    AND pr.pg =  st.pg
```

Comment: Unfortunately it fails on the `H4` lines: fields of `pr` are `NULL` (see expected result in the question). Thank you anyway.

Comment: Off course it fails. Just wanted to show how to write the `FROM` part.